# Get Error "Class 'Facebook\FacebookPermissionException' not found"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want post new feeds on my facebook . This is code use SDK 4.0

```
session_start();
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
```

init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)

```
 FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('','');
```

login helper with redirect_uri

```
 $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://example.com' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  try {
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
        'link' => 'www.example.com',
        'message' => 'User provided message'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }


} else {
 // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
```

I have been received error "Class 'Facebook\FacebookPermissionException' not found"

Please help me. Many thank

Answer (score 3):

The class hasn't been included in your code.

Right after this:

```
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
```

Add:

```
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );
```